# JMeter JSON path extract value without array brackets []

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

I need the value out of an array, not the array brackets[ ].  Here is the JSON response I am trying to work with:

```
{
:   "@rpc":"1.0",
:   "@types":
:   [
:   :   "com.model.chart.PieChart",
:   :   "com.model.chart.PieChartData"
:   ],
:   "@data":
:   {
:   :   "@type":0,
:   :   "chartData":
:   :   [
:   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   "@type":1,
:   :   :   :   "data":0.0,
:   :   :   :   "name":"Yes"
:   :   :   },
:   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   "@type":1,
:   :   :   :   "data":13.0,
:   :   :   :   "name":"No"
:   :   :   }
:   :   ],
:   :   "subTitle":"Over Time Period",
:   :   "dataName":"MyData",
:   :   "title":"MyData Requirement"
:   }
}
```

I am trying to get just the data for the yes and no.  So for no, I just want to get 13.0 but I continue getting [13.0] with the array brackets.  Here are the values of JSONPath Expressions I have tried:

`$.@data.chartData..[?(@.name=='No')].data` returns [13.0]

`$.@data.chartData..[?(@.name=='No')].data[0]` returns nothing

`$.@data.chartData..[?(@.name=='No')][0].data` returns nothing

`$.@data.chartData[0]..[?(@.name=='No')].data` returns nothing

I am using version 2.3 of the JSON plugin in my jmeter v 3.0.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Option 1: looking into the [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) given you use `data` as a reference name and receiving `[13.0]` you can get `13` without brackets as `${data_1}`

  [image: JMeter JSON Path Extractor]

  - Option 2: since JMeter 3.0 you have [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) which behaves a little bit differently and returns the data without square brackets:

  [image: JSON Path Postprocessor]

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and using JMeter (version 3.2), I didn't get the square [] brackets.  However, make sure you use "JSON Extractor" and not "jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor."